# Is it possible to get type of a static method on a class using an instance of that class?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to use an instance of a class `Foo` to get to the type of the static function `bar`, is this possible?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/AQ4YwGwQwZx4BiB7JwDeBYAUKXwYAuUBAlmMAEZQBOwAFAG4BclKEAplAHYCU62eQcGrsCAV2pdgDAUIC%20skApyhF4JF0LAAZimABeYF3YB3RCjo81AemvAAFuxHAAkgHIAtsALUAniS4Ac29UMRh2HRQAGmBuYADCbjAIpG1zJBs7EngSAmAAByQ4EgoOYDCA4N1UAlQoMGS4Sho3eAJffPY1ds7I1EMe9lS%207o6IhgM%20gG03MA1CajEwWuo3AF0ZqlW14FtgABMkdnguJDyTJGoAazVM73ts4Avr%20BNHKV8kMQcoBgj6xptGqOcDQOCjXoAD0mg2GyAyKhAg2atEMkM2LTWQA)

```
class Foo {
    static bar (v: boolean) {
        return v
    }
}

const foo = new Foo()
// here I'm trying to use foo, an instance of Foo
// is it possible using foo to access bar's type
type foo = typeof foo
type v = foo['constructor']['bar'] // does not work

// this works when you have access to the class
type x = typeof Foo
type bar = x['bar']
```